# Template error when displaying hostname in Spring Boot sample application - pet clinic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using the sample spring-petclinic Spring Boot app for a demo I'm building. I'm trying to do something that seems super basic, but am struggling (I'm a Java n00b).

Here's the sample app: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

Essentially I want to display the server hostname on the welcome page of the website.

In the WelcomeController.java file (`spring-petclinic/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/system/WelcomeController.java`) I have the following:

```
package org.springframework.samples.petclinic.system;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Hello from " + System.getenv("HOSTNAME") + String.format("%n");
    }
}
```

All I have replaced is the return value from `return "welcome"` to what you see above.

The build completes and I can run the application, but the page loads with the following error:

```
Something happened...

Error resolving template "Hello from d7710dcc2456 ", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I've played around with model.addAttribute and adding additional `public String` blocks, but am a little out of my depth! Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to display this on the client, why don't you get the value from client using `window.location` ?

Comment: It's not so much retrieving the hostname value, as that is returned on the page correctly. It's more the template error in Spring

Comment: I edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a String value from a controller method with @RequestMapping, spring will resolve the string value from
configured view template. So return "welcome" resolves the welcome.html inside `resources/templates/` directory.

When you replace it with return "Hello from " + System.getenv("HOSTNAME") + String.format("%n") 
it will look for the template with name "Hello from " + System.getenv("HOSTNAME") + String.format("%n")

As this is not present inside `resources/templates/`, it gives error.

Change your controller like this:

```
@GetMapping("/") 
public String welcome(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("hostname", System.getenv("HOSTNAME") );
    return "welcome"; 
}
```

And change your welcome.html like this,

```
<h1>Hello from <span th:text="${hostname}">hostname</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me get it working. In the end I had to add the following to the controller `import org.springframework.ui.Model;` and this in the html file `<h1>Hello from <span th:text="${hostname}">hostname</span></h1>`

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE - after edit the question**

To get `hostname` of running machine, try the following

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

String hostname;
try {
    InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    hostname =  ia.getHostName();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//assuming your thymeleaf template file called 'welcome'
model.addAttribute("hostname", hostname);
return "welcome";
```

And in your template file

```
<h1>Hello from <span th:text="${hostname}">hostname</span></h1>
```